# Push Table to screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jstree

I have an AJAX request when a branch of my JSSTree is clicked

```
$("#jstree").bind("select_node.jstree", function(evt, data)
 {      
      var idArgument = data.node.text;
      $.ajax(
      {
           type: "POST",
           url: "WebForm1.aspx/brancheSelectionnee",
           data: JSON.stringify({ id: idArgument }),
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: function(msg) 
           {
                ;
           }
       });
 });
```

So, I call this function, which make a new "page" (because it's static) and call a function that return a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table`.

```
public static string brancheSelectionnee(string id)
{
    var page = (WebForm1)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table tableau = page.brancheSelectionneeNonStatique(id);

   var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
   using (var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
   {
       tableau.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
   }
   string tableauString=stringWriter.ToString();
   return "randomstring";
}
```

Big problem here: My "tableau" is updated, with what I want (I see this with the htmlWriter) but.. I don't know how put it in my screen!
I have it in my C# code, but I want it in the screen, and not just here.

I have "tableauArticle" which is a real `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table`, in my ASP.net code.
I tried some things, like putting "tableauArticle" as Static, then

```
  tableauArticles = tableau;
```

But I didn't see any changement. I think that I updated a table in the page that I don't display

I think that the main problem is that my pagee isn't refresh or I do my tables wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the answer, it is 100% Raidri solution :

```
 $('#tableauArticles').empty();
 $('<div class="newtable">').html(msg.d).appendTo('#tableauArticles');
```

Comment: When an answer answers your question / solves your problem you should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Answer (score 2):

You do an AJAX request, so there is no page refresh. You just get a string (with HTML) back from your server method. You then have to manually put that string on your page. This happens in the `success` callback function which in your code is empty. As first step try something like this:

```
success: function(msg) 
{
    $('<div class="newtable">').html(msg).appendTo('body');
}
```

On the server-side your method `brancheSelectionnee` needs the `AjaxMethod` attribute so that it can be called with AJAX:

```
[Ajax.AjaxMethod()]
public static string brancheSelectionnee(string id)
```

(It also should `return tableauString;` not `"randomstring"`, right?. And I am not sure if you can use the `HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler` there, but that is for a second step if the basic AJAX stuff works.)

Here is one [tutorial](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) for all this which gives you an overview.

Comment: I'll try this immediatly :
The "randomstring" was for tests, just like  HtmlTextWriter : It was just for seeing if my table has the goods cells in, but I'll use it to display the table =) Thanks, I'll update asap

Comment: Actually, 'brancheSelectionnee ' have just ' [WebMethod]' and not ' [AJAXMethod]' 

The string returned is something like "<table>\r\n\t<tr>\r\n\t\t<td>TextInCell</td><td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Read\" /></td>\r\n\t</tr>\r\n</table>"

Comment: So, now I'm able to update a label, I'll see how update dynamicly a table =)